# Beginning to solve inequalitity

Tags: inequality

Hi I just started to inequality 
I came across this Q I don't get how to solve
show that

$$(a^2-b^2)(c^2-d^2)\le(ac-bd)^2$$
and
$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\ge(ac+bd)^2$$
for all a,b,c,d and the sign of equality holds if and only if ad=bc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity), i.e.,
$$
(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2,
$$
and 
$$
(a^2-b^2)(c^2-d^2)=(ac-bd)^2-(ad-bc)^2
$$